# how to prohibit data from exporting outside project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to prohibit project member from exporting data to other project, like prohibiting "Copy Table" or "Export Table" or "save as Table". How should I set user IAM setting?

Thanks!

Comment: are you asking about prohibiting of doing export at all, or just to prohibit export to different projects while still allowing export withing the same project?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to prohibit export to different projects while still allowing export withing the same project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bigquery.tables.export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions) permission is the one that grants such abilities ("Export table data out of BigQuery"). Said permission is included in most of predefined roles of BigQuery, except in the BigQuery User role.

You could grant that role to said member, or [create a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) with all the permissions that you want to grant to the member, avoiding the `bigquery.tables.export` permission as mentioned.